# How to Convert Applet to JFrame

Tags: java, swing, applet, jframe, japplet

This is Our code for our game. we had it as an applet viewer before and we tried converting to jframe but it keeps giving us `ClassCastException` errors. Please help us convert from applet to jframe. Here's the code and tell us what to do?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.*;


public class gg extends JFrame implements MouseListener
{   
    private JButton table[][];     
    //private boolean bomb[][];    
//  private boolean flag[][];      
    private boolean exposed[][]; 
    //private boolean checkwinbool[][]; 
    private int row = 16, col = 30; 
    private int sizex = 780, sizey = 492;
    private Font f ;
    private JPanel P;
    private JLabel TimeRemaning, NG;
    private JButton RestartE, RestartM, RestartH;
    private GridLayout gl;



    public gg() {

        setLayout (new BorderLayout ());
        gl = new GridLayout (row, col);
        P = new JPanel (gl);
        f = new Font ("ComicSans", Font.BOLD, 17);
        setFont (f);
        TimeRemaning = new JLabel ("");
        NG = new JLabel ("New Game");
        RestartE = new JButton ("Easy");


        table = new JButton [row] [col];
        //flag = new boolean [row] [col];
        exposed = new boolean [row] [col];
        //checkwinbool = new boolean [row] [col];
        for (int x = 0 ; x < row ; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0 ; y < col ; y++)
            {
                table [x] [y] = new JButton ();
                table [x] [y].addMouseListener (this);
                P.add (table [x] [y]);
            }
        }
        //these for loops set up the buttons and sets all the boolean arrays to = false

        add (P, "Center");
        NG.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        NG.setForeground(Color.black);
        Restart_Game (row, col, row, col, sizex, sizey);



    }


    public void Restart_Game (int row, int col, int prow, int pcol, int sizex, int sizey)
    {

        setSize (sizex, sizey);
        invalidate();
        validate();
        gl.setRows (row);
        gl.setColumns (col);

        for (int x = 0 ; x < prow ; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0 ; y < pcol ; y++)
            {
                P.remove (table [x] [y]);
            }
        }
        for (int x = 0 ; x < row ; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0 ; y < col ; y++)
            {

                table [x] [y].setEnabled (true);

                table [x] [y].setBackground (Color.gray);
                table [x] [y].setForeground (Color.white);
                P.add (table [x] [y]);
                //flag [x] [y] = false;
                exposed [x] [y] = false;
                //checkwinbool [x] [y] = false;
            }
        }
        setSize (sizex, sizey);
        invalidate();
        validate();


    }


    public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getSource () == RestartE)
        {
            row = 10;
            col = 10;
            sizex = 300;
            sizey = 346;
        }
    }
```

1. List item

   ```
   public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
   public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
   public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {    }
   public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}}
   ```

Comment: *"... tell us what to do?"* - You read the stacktrace, and fix the bug.  Since you didn't bother to include it in the question, it is unlikely that we can help you.

Comment: [Look here](http://www.google.co.il/search?q=java+convert+applet+to+application).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot convert one class to another you need to redesign your program. Something like this:

```
public class GameBoard extends JPanel {

     // all your stuff from gg class
}

public class GameFrame extends JFrame {

    public GameFrame() {
        add(new GameBoard());
    }
}

public class GameApplet extends JApplet {

    public GameApplet() {
        add(new GameBoard());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `JApplet` with `JFrame` and add the main method `public static void main( String[] args ) { gg gg = new gg(); }` just before the last }.